# Populating Vue data based on response from axios GET request

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

Imagine I make a GET request to an API endpoint that will return 10 images like this:

```
export default {
    data: function() {
        return {
            images: []
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        axios.get('https://api.unsplash.com/photos/?client_id=secret')
        .then(response => {
            for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
                this.images.push(response.data[i]);
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    }
}
```

Do I have to initialize an empty images array and then populate it with the response using a for loop like I have done in my code, or is that unnecessary? I can't really think of any other way to loop through the returned images unless I actually store them myself in my own variable.

Comment: what do you mean? if you can write the "plain for loop" in some other way? why you can't do `this.images = response.data;`?

Comment: Do I have to create the images array data and push all objects to it myself like I have currently done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with this. It's much cleaner to just assign it though, since you're only getting the images once in the mounted hook.

```
export default {
    data: function() {
        return {
            images: []
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        axios.get('https://api.unsplash.com/photos/?client_id=secret')
        .then(response => {
            this.images = response.data;
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, I didn't know I could do that. Definitely cleaner.

Comment: Just make sure you have the property properly defined in your data options so that Vue can react to it no problems. You still need to loop/push though if you're gonna load more images later on, or you can use `array.concat()` and reassign again.